# MultiRNN is not working with list of same BasicLSTM cells

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Following code is failing when same Basic cells are used `(cell1, cell1)` for `MultiRNNCell`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128,reuse=False, name = "cell1")
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128,reuse=False,name = "cell2")
multi = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell1] )
init = multi.zero_state(64, tf.float32)
output,state = multi(tf.ones([64,512]),init)
```

Where as this code is working with `(cell1, cell2)`. But `cell2` is same as `cell1`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128,reuse=False, name = "cell1")
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128,reuse=False,name = "cell2")
multi = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell2] )
init = multi.zero_state(64, tf.float32)
output,state = multi(tf.ones([64,512]),init)
```

May I know the difference in both code examples?

An error is this:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 256 and 640 for 'multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/cell1/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [64,256], [640,512].

Answer (score 2):

It is a known limitation (e.g. discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386307/712995)). The problem is that each cell instance creates an internal variable for the weights. The dimensionality of this variable is determined by the hidden size (`128` in your case) and the input size that this cell instance receives (`512`). When you use **the same cell multiple times**, you must ensure that the input is the same in all cases.

Consider your sample code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
cell1 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128,reuse=False, name = "cell1")
cell2 = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(128,reuse=False,name = "cell2")
multi = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([cell1, cell1] )
init = multi.zero_state(64, tf.float32)
output,state = multi(tf.ones([64,512]),init)
```

The inputs to the two cells in `multi` will be `[..., 640]` and `[..., 256]`, because `640=512+128` (the cell receives the input from the previous cell as well as from the input sequence). Hence the weights matrix inside of them will be **`[640, 512]`** and **`[256, 512]`** (`512` here is actually `128*4`, not the input size).

But you're using the same cell instance! Tensorflow tries to match the matrix it already has with the new input and fails. On the other hand, when you're using different instances, tensorflow is able to instantiate different matrices for different layers and work out the shapes correctly.