# Tensorflow seq2seq regression model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, seq2seq

I have simple seq2seq model for predicting stock prices.I have create an encoder of lstm cells and decoder which will predict the next 5 timesteps values.But it throws error:

```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 517 and 562 for 'rnn/while/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/MatMul_1' (op: 'MatMul') with input shapes: [10,517], [562,2048].
```

Sample of data

```
               t1     t2     t3     t4    t5 ...
19/10/2018   0.005  0.100 -0.021 0.030 -0.025
20/10/2018   0.023  0.020  0.020 0.130  0.125
21/10/2018  -0.205  0.140 -0.011 0.020 -0.305
```

Code

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

seq_len = 1
n_inputs = 50
n_outputs = 5
n_layers = 3
n_neurons = 512
batch_size = 10

g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
  X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,seq_len,n_inputs),name="X")
  y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,seq_len,n_outputs),name="y")

  cells = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([ tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n_neurons) for _ in range(n_layers) ])

  init_state = cells.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)
  enc_outputs, enc_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, X,initial_state=init_state)

  dec_outputs,dec_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cells, y, initial_state=enc_states)

  loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(dec_outputs - y))
  train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

  init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session(graph=g)
sess.run(init)
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I could not mark your question as a duplicate, because it has a bounty on it. You are getting the error because you *must* not reuse the same cell for the first layer, as well as the deeper layers. This is because the inputs given to them are different, which makes the kernel matrices different. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48386307/11059315) post, this should fix the error:

> ```py
> # Extra function is for readability. No problem to inline it.
> def make_cell(lstm_size):
>   return tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_size, state_is_tuple=True)
>
> network = rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([make_cell(num_units) for _ in range(num_layers)], 
>                                 state_is_tuple=True)
> ```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48372994/11059315) is more help on this issue.

Comment: I should have same number of n_inputs and n_outputs?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou I am not very sure as i don't use tensorflow much. But I think you should have the same outputs. Good luck!

Comment: Do you use keras?

Comment: @MariosNikolaou -- No. Only tensorflow.

Comment: encoder initial state should be set to zero? `init_state = cells.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)`

Comment: @MariosNikolaou --Maybe. I'm not sure. Why don't you try it out? I think it will work.

Comment: @MariosNikolaou You do not need to put the same number of inputs and ouputs.

Comment: @BCJuan how i will do it?